# Very slow response from Azure App Service

Tags: .net, azure, performance

Since a few weeks, I see very long response times from my webapp. It's a .NET app hosted in an App Service on Azure. I'm talking >20 seconds for a simple request.

In the following request, the webapp gets a request, it checks if the authentication token is valid, then it queries the database and run some simple code to return some json back.

To use this .NET backend service, user needs to be authenticated with Azure AD, we're using a JWT token for that. Every time the webserver receives some request, it directly asks the Azure AD if the user is authenticated. There is almost no code touched before that Azure AD request is fired.

Normally everything above (check auth, do db query, parse request to json) should cost <500ms.

But now, sometimes, we can see this in Application Insights:

[image: Application Insights screenshot]

What I see is that the webserver 'hangs' for around **12 seconds** before it asks Azure AD if the token is valid!

Besides, everything what's happening after that, costs also way too much time. I also don't understand the gap between the two database requests. The second request could never take >1000ms, but in the screenshot it does.

We got a lot of those slow responses around the same timeframe. An hour later, everything is back and snappy (then the striped bars from screenshot starts right after each other, like its supposed to), and another hour later, its back slow again.

**I have no idea where I can start my search**. I hope you guys could give me some search directions and/or ideas why this could happen.

I already checked the CPU load and memory load of the server. It is sometimes high (peaks >80%) but I don't see clear bottlenecks around 100%. Also, that load is relatively constant and shares no peaks with the slow moments, so I don't think the problem is there.

Edit: I used the Web Service Diagnostic to check out if that can give me some directions. Here I see the following thing:

[image]

`HandlerChanged From(ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0) to (System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler)` and `ManagedPipelineHandler`.
Does anyone know what that is and how I can debug that?

Comment: inspect the "Diagnose and solve problems" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics  and see if there's something else besides what App Insights is showing to you

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thank you. I see at the 'Web App Slow', it counts 10.000 requests with the message `HandlerChanged From(ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0) to (System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler)`.

Any idea what that is?

I will also add this information to my question.

Comment: seems to be IIS handler, but I'm not 100% sure. There's a chance you're exceeding TCP connections and some of them are being queued, what can be the reason of those delays

Comment: I'm doing some outbound TCP connections with the app, so that's indeed possible. But; we're running an S3 appservice and I understand I can do 8064 connections with that, we're definitely not using so many connections... 
What's the best place to find if that's happening?

Comment: first link I've shared: "Diagnose and solve problems" learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics

Comment: I'm sorry, first I didn't see the "TCP connections" tab. But when I click on it, it says "No issues with outbound TCP Connections detected". Tops outbound <400 requests, and on S3 it shoud do 8000 without problems. So I don't think that's it... Do you have any more idea's?

Comment: there should be a section related to slow responses.

Comment: That page only tells me the message above: "We analyzed 10000 slow requests and identified module(s) consuming most of the time are - HandlerChanged From(ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0) to (System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler)"

But I'm not sure what that is and how I can debug that. You said its probably TCP connections, but I see only ~400 where the bottleneck should be 8000. Also the spikes in TCP connections do not correlate with timestamps when response is slow.

Do you have any tips how I can find more info about this; how I can debug it?

Comment: not really .... unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same issue after I added the setting WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG on my app and my deployment slots according to the tips on the blog of RuslanY (https://ruslany.net/2019/06/azure-app-service-deployment-slots-tips-and-tricks/) . Last friday I removed the setting and since that time the issue has not occurred anymore. I guess something in the ExtentionlessUrlHandler class uses WCF as RuslanY warned about in the blog. No other explanation comes to mind, but I'm very happy it is resolved with my app. Hopefully this will help you as well.